# Totally isotropic line-spreads

Tags: co.combinatorics

Consider the finite projective space PG(5,q), any q, equipped with a symplectic form f. Does there exist a symplectic line spread of PG(5,q)? (a partition of PG(5,q) into q^4+q^2+1 lines that are totally isotropic with respect to f).
As far as I know there exists an example in PG(5,3) stabilized by PSL(2,13) (as a subgroup of PSp(6,3)). Other examples?